# custom validation with array in loopback

Tags: validation, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

**Does anyone know how to do custom validation on array of sub model in loopback.js?**

```
"properties": {
"rows": {
  "type": [
    "sub-model"
  ],
  "required": true
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi Chaudhary - can you describe what approaches you have considered or tried, and what success you've had with them and what problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `model.js` you need to add below :

```
function rowsValidation(err){
  if(!this.rows){
    err();
  }
}

Model.validate('rows', rowsValidation, {message: 'Rows is not valid'});
```